# CoverFlow like Slideshow

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, slideshow, coverflow

I stuck again at a Problem.

I want to make a little Slideshow (functionality like CoverFlow -> Thumbnails can scroll horizontally).
I have 10 Pictures that should be as Thumbnails in this show. when i "press" a pic, this pic should go fullscreen.
Can anyone give me a little help or even a tutorial to do such a thing?

Thank You ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [OpenFlow](http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/) for an open source replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the Link!
But how will it be when i want to distribute this via the AppStore? I read something about that apple dont want that dev's use open source API's.

Comment: No Apple does not want you to use *private* APIs.